How can I get the mq-golang library to work with the IBM MQ container image on Apple M1 or ARM64 platforms?
I built and ran an IBM MQ container image natively on M1 Apple Silicon by running
git clone https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-container.git

cd mq-container

make build-devserver

Then I wrote a simple Dockerfile for my Golang application that attempts to talk to the queue manager using mq-golang-jms20
FROM ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev:9.4.0.0-arm64 AS mq

FROM arm64v8/golang:1.22-bullseye AS builder

# set working dir
WORKDIR /app

# copy files and download deps
COPY go.* ./
RUN go mod download

# copy entire app code to working dir
COPY . ./

# update builder container to install MQ Golang libs (it depends on the native C client)
RUN mkdir -p /opt/mqm && chmod a+rx /opt/mqm

COPY --chown=0:0 --from=mq /opt/mqm /opt/mqm

RUN GOOS=darwin GOARCH=arm64 go build -v -o server ./main.go

I built my image using docker-compose with this docker-compose file
services:
  mq:
    image: ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev:9.4.0.0-arm64
    container_name: ibm-mq-container
    environment:
      - LICENSE=accept
      - MQ_QMGR_NAME=QM1
      - MQ_APP_PASSWORD=password
      - MQ_ADMIN_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - 1414:1414
      - 9443:9443
    volumes:
      - qm1data:/mnt/mqm
    networks:
      - webapi_network
    restart: unless-stopped

DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/arm64 docker compose -f "docker/docker-compose.yml" up -d --build

But it complains with
0.318 /go/pkg/mod/github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-golang-jms20@v1.10.0/jms20subset/MQOptions.go:5:32: undefined: ibmmq.MQCNO
0.318 /go/pkg/mod/github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-golang-jms20@v1.10.0/jms20subset/MQOptions.go:8:25: undefined: ibmmq.MQCNO

I've scoured the internet for a possible solution but can't seem to find one. Does anyone know how to make mq-golang-jms20 work with ARM64 mq-container image? For context, this works fine with the older images built for AMD64 platform instead.

You appear to be mixing up things for native MacOS with the Linux container that runs the queue manager.
If you want to run application code inside the same Linux container as the queue manager, then you proabbly should not be setting GOOS=Darwin when trying to compile the application.
Alternatively, you can install the MQ Client (and SDK) to run on MacOS directly, and compile in that environment. Use brew to install the SDK.

And the default container build from the Dockerfile does not include the SDK (which is basically the header files like cmqc.h). It strips it, as the main purpose of that container is to get a running queue manager. If you really want to build something inside that Linux environment, then change the Dockerfile so that genmqpkg_incsdk=1

@MarkTaylor I redacted that part from the docker-compose.yml in my question. I have a separate Linux container for my application code that talks to the queue manager. The error I see is at compile time before my application container could launch.

As per the comments, there are a number of ways to do this depending on what you are trying to achieve.
I am assuming that you want to build and test a container, before running it in the cloud. In which case there isn't an ARM64 linux redist IBM MQ client, so you have to use the X86, and tell docker / Podman on your Apple Silicon to build for --platform linux/amd64
This is the dockerfile I use to build and run my go messaging apps on a MacOS machine.

###########################################################
# This starts the BUILD phase
###########################################################
FROM golang:1.22 as builder

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends curl bash 

RUN mkdir -p /opt/mqm && chmod a+rx /opt/mqm

# Location of the downloadable MQ client package \
ENV MQARCH=X64
ENV RDURL="https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/messaging/mqdev/redist" \
    RDTAR="IBM-MQC-Redist-Linux${MQARCH}.tar.gz" \
    VRMF=9.3.5.0

# Install the MQ client from the Redistributable package. This also contains the
# header files we need to compile against. Setup the subset of the package
# we are going to keep - the genmqpkg.sh script removes unneeded parts
ENV genmqpkg_incnls=1 \
    genmqpkg_incsdk=1 \
    genmqpkg_inctls=1

RUN cd /opt/mqm \
 && curl -LO "$RDURL/$VRMF-$RDTAR" \
 && tar -zxf ./*.tar.gz \
 && rm -f ./*.tar.gz \
 && bin/genmqpkg.sh -b /opt/mqm


# Build the messaging app

ENV APP_DIR /usr/src
WORKDIR ${APP_DIR}

COPY ./msg-app ./msgapp
WORKDIR ${APP_DIR}/msgapp

ENV CGO_CFLAGS "-I/opt/mqm/inc/"
ENV CGO_LDFLAGS_ALLOW "-Wl,-rpath.*"

RUN rm msgapp || true 
RUN go build


# ###########################################################
# # This starts the RUNTIME phase
# ########################################################### 
FROM golang:1.22 

ENV MQ_ROOT /opt/mqm

COPY --from=builder ${MQ_ROOT} ${MQ_ROOT}

ENV APP_DIR /usr/src/msgapp
WORKDIR ${APP_DIR}

# Copy over just the application and the environment files 
COPY --from=builder ${APP_DIR}/consumer ${APP_DIR}/msgapp
COPY --from=builder ${APP_DIR}/ccdt.json ${APP_DIR}/ccdt.json


CMD ["./msgapp"]


I use Podman to build and run containers, in this case
podman build --platform linux/amd64 -t mq-consumer -f Dockerfile.msgapp .

forcing the platform to be amd64 / X64.
If all you want to do is run a go messaging application on your Mac, then there is a universal IBM MQ client toolkit that you can install with brew.
brew tap ibm-messaging/ibmmq

brew install ibm-messaging/ibmmq/mqdevtoolkit

If you do want to run ARM64 messaging apps inside a container, then you will need to base on the IBM MQ container image, and modify it so that it contains the requisite SDK to be a able to build a client app.
